# Creating a react npm package getting dependencies error when importing

Tags: reactjs, npm, package, rollup, react-dom

Hello i am trying to publish a react component as an npm package so later i can install it rather than importing the same files all over again

i followed a tutorial i found online everything went smoothly but when i try to import the package in the new solution i get the following error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState') it's like the dependencies are not being defined or somehting

i am using Rollup and react typescript

console logs:

Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')

valid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

this is my rollup config file

```
  {
    input: "src/index.ts",
    output: [
      {
        file: packageJsonExample1.main,
        format: "cjs",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
      {
        file: packageJsonExample1.module,
        format: "esm",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      resolve(),
      commonjs(),
      typescript({ tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json" }),
    ],
  },

  {
    input: "dist/esm/types/index.d.ts",
    output: [{ file: "dist/index.d.ts", format: "esm" }],
    plugins: [dts()],
  },
```

Comment: I have just answered a similar question here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76382725/import-react-components-from-one-app-into-another-ts-react-app/76439577#76439577
Hope this helps