# Import React Components from one app into another TS React App

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, rollup

I have recently made two applications, one that is supposed to be a component library with complex logic inside, for instance, a component that should render a view with two or three components inside, each with useRefs, useStates and whatnot.

However, when I try to build those components, and export them through TSC / rollup into my other application, upon importing them I get this error:

```
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
```

If the components are simple text, they work just fine, but as soon as you add some React functionality such as useState, like in the following example it can't no longer be used from the other application.

Library project:

```
import React from "react";

const HelloWorld: React.FC = () => {
  const text = "";
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);
  return (
    <div>
      {counter}
      <button onClick={() => setCounter(counter + 1)}>+</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCounter(counter - 1)}>-</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HelloWorld;
```

I am importing the component like such:

Receiving project: (Both react)

```
import React from 'react';
import { HelloWorld } from 'component-library-starter';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <HelloWorld />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

How is that something so simple, doesn't work? I have tried to build with tsc instead, import directly, etc. But nothing seems to work, I clearly am doing something wrong, but I can't see what :(

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This issue is very likely caused by the fact that it carries over it's own version of React instead of using the same one. Is there a build process like Webpack for `component-library-starter`, or, what happens if you `npm ls react`, are they "deduped"?

Comment: Oh, you mention "rollup", you should check https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#external

Comment: @JakubKotrs Yes, there was many versions that were deduped. I managed to fix it following this guide https://legacy.reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#duplicate-react 
But, it works locally in these two projects, I am unsure as to whether that will be a problem in production, and for when devs pull this separate projects. It seems like a hacky solution.

Comment: @JakubKotrs I just read your second comment, that link looks very promising! I will give it a thorough read. Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, the issue might be caused because there are two versions of React in the receiving project, one in the bundle created by Rollup from the library and another in the receiving project.

I had the same issue and solved it by adding react and react-dom as a peer dependency in the package.json in the library project. Then in the rollup config you should add **externals**.

This is my rollup config for your reference.

```
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
import dts from "rollup-plugin-dts";
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";
import image from "@rollup/plugin-image";

import packageJson from "./package.json" assert { type: "json" };

export default [
    {
        input: "src/main.ts",
        output: [
            {
                file: packageJson.main,
                format: "cjs",
                sourcemap: true,
            },
            {
                file: packageJson.module,
                format: "esm",
                sourcemap: true,
            },
        ],
        plugins: [
            resolve(),
            commonjs(),

            typescript({ tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json" }),
            image(),
            postcss({ extract: false, modules: true, use: ["sass"] }),
        ],
        external: Object.keys(packageJson.peerDependencies),
    },
    {
        input: "dist/esm/types/main.d.ts",
        output: [{ file: "dist/index.d.ts", format: "esm" }],
        plugins: [dts()],

        external: [/\.css$/],
    },
];
```

The external property basically tells rollup not to include the peer dependencies in the final bundle. Those dependencies must then be included in the receiving project.

Hope this helps!